# APC (Alternate PHP Cache) Throwing Lots of PHP Notices

Tags: php, apc, e-notices

I got APC 3.1.9 setup on my Linux box running PHP 5.3.6.

Caching works fine but I have noticed in our error logs, that APC throws a lot of PHP notices, such as:

> [Wed Jun 29 01:08:56 2011] [error]
>   [client ip] PHP Notice: 
>   require_once() [function.require-once]:
>   apc_cache_find [16085954]\n in
>   /path/to/file on line 75, referer:
>   /path/to/referer/file
>
> [Wed Jun 29 01:08:56 2011] [error]
>   [client ip] PHP Notice: 
>   require_once() [function.require-once]:
>   1. h->opened_path=[/path/to/file]  h->filename=[/path/to/file]\n in
>   /path/to/file on line 84, referer:
>   /path/to/referer/file
>
> [Wed Jun 29 01:08:56 2011] [error]
>   [client ip] PHP Notice:  Unknown:
>   apc_cache_find [16215361]\n in Unknown
>   on line 0, referer:
>   /path/to/referer/file

--> /path/to/file & /path/to/referer/file have been inserted by me replacing the original file names

Any idea why APC throws all these messages ?

Comment: figured it out, debugging was enabled. Re-installed APC and disabled debugging during installation...

Comment: Would you mind posting how you did that in an answer?

Answer (score 14):

The exact installation line when installing/reinstalling APC is this:

```
Enable internal debugging in APC [no] :no
```

Comment: I should note that if you just hit <Enter> when going through the pre-build prompts in PECL, it appears to default to yes. That is, I hit <Enter> and it gave me the notices mentioned above on each page load.

If you want to reinstall via PECL, btw, you have to do pecl uninstall apc first.

Comment: How can I disable in my case?? 
I tried copying the dll to ext/ folder and modifying the ini file.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late for Mike, but I found a solution (APC 3.1.9 / 3.1.13) :

You can also follow this :

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59445

Where it is said :

"If compiling is not an option, roll back to stable: pecl install -f APC-3.1.6"

It is indeed a regression, but it worked fine for me :)

Comment: I had the same problem & that has been resolved now.. Thanks Benj

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall and reinstall apc, typing “no” to disable debugging:

```
pecl uninstall apc

pecl install apc
    Enable internal debugging in APC [no] : no
```

Restart apache:
    `#service httpd restart`
or 
    `#/etc/init.d/apache restart`

Answer (score 0):

And also this problem's cause it can be php version. 
(So PHP version changes / mismatch. in particular, If the moved web site. You should check.)

Good luck!