# Installing Symfony 2.5: blank welcome page | apc_cache_find notice

Tags: php, symfony, apc

I'm trying to install Symfony2 (I use 'Bitnami' localhost on Windows). When I open `http://localhost:8080/symfony2/web/config.php` I see the config page, after goint to welcome page blank page is displayed.

On `http://localhost:8080/symfony2/web/app_dev.php` I've turned `ini_set("display_errors", "1");`   and what I get is:

> Notice: require_once(): 1.
>   h->opened_path=[C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.26-0\apache2\htdocs\symfony2\app\bootstrap.php.cache]
>   h->filename=[C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.26-0\apache2\htdocs\symfony2\app\bootstrap.php.cache]
>   in
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.26-0\apache2\htdocs\symfony2\web\app_dev.php
>   on line 27
>
> Notice: require_once(): apc_cache_find [-1630956134] in
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.26-0\apache2\htdocs\symfony2\web\app_dev.php
>   on line 27
>
> Notice: require_once(): 1.
>   h->opened_path=[C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.26-0\apache2\htdocs\symfony2\app\autoload.php]
>   h->filename=[C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.26-0\apache2\htdocs\symfony2\app\autoload.php]
>   in
>   C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.26-0\apache2\htdocs\symfony2\app\bootstrap.php.cache
>   on line 3

And further errors similar to these.
I saw this: [APC (Alternate PHP Cache) Throwing Lots of PHP Notices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518068/apc-alternate-php-cache-throwing-lots-of-php-notices?rq=1)

But I'm not sure what should I do with `Enable internal debugging in APC [no] :no`

I'm stuck. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is currently no APC module for PHP5.5 on Windows so you have to use another cache module. You did not write which Xampp version you are using, but I suppose a more recent one.

Please try to use APCu and enable it in php.ini

```
extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_apcu.dll"
apc.enabled = 1
```

It worked for me on Windows.

Also, Zend released in PHP5.5 their new OPCache as an alternative to APC. More info can be found here [enter link description here](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/using_php_5_5_s). Could be also useful but I never tried that one.

Comment: Yep, I've switched off apc and it works. Thank you (I use wampstack 5.4.26)